# how to implement ng-show right way?

Tags: angularjs

can someone check my code and tell me how to make it in right way?
it works but i don't think this is the right
if i would have 20 sub menus,i would need to create 20 functions,which is definitely wrong
thank you in advance

```
<ul class="menu-top">
              <li ng-click="menu2show()">drinks</li>
              <li ng-click="menu1show()">food</li>
              <li ng-click="menu3show()">desserts</li>
</ul>
<div id="menu-content" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
                 <div class="menu1"  ng-show="show1" >
                    <div  class="item" ng-repeat="item in menu.menu1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu2" ng-show="show2" >
                    <div  class="item" ng-repeat="item in menu.menu2">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu3" ng-show="show3" >
                    <div  class="item" ng-repeat="item in menu.menu3">

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.menu = {
        menu1:[
                {"name":"item1", "price":"1", "desc":"aaa"},
                {"name":"item2", "price":"2", "desc":"bbb"},
                {"name":"item3", "price":"3", "desc":"ccc"},
             ],
        menu2:[
                {"name":"item8", "price":"6", "desc":"zzz"},
                {"name":"item9", "price":"4", "desc":"xxx"},
                {"name":"item10", "price":"2", "desc":"sss"},
            ],
        menu3:[
            {"name":"item15", "price":"3", "desc":"mmmm"},
            {"name":"item16", "price":"1", "desc":"nnn"},
            {"name":"item17", "price":"5", "desc":"bbb"},
        ]};
      $scope.show1 = true;  

    $scope.menu1show = function(){
        $scope.show1 = true;
        $scope.show2 = false;
        $scope.show3 = false;
      }
    $scope.menu2show = function(){
        $scope.show1 = false;
        $scope.show2 = true ;
        $scope.show3 = false;
    }

     $scope.menu3show = function(){
        $scope.show1 = false ;
        $scope.show2 = false ;
        $scope.show3 = true ;
    }
});
```

Comment: If `$scope.menu` was an array, you could just loop through it using ng-repeat

Comment: what would that change?please explain.thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make a scope variable to capture the menu that you wish to display.

```
$scope.showMenu = 1;
```

Then for each menu:

```
 <div class="menu2" ng-show="showMenu === 2" >
 ...
 <div class="menu1" ng-show="showMenu === 1" >
```

and so on.

And for the click:

```
  <li ng-click="showMenu = 2">drinks</li>
```

and so on.